# What are the various parameters i can pass to <animated> from react-spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I have just started working on react-spring. From the very beginning, I have seen the usage of '''<animated>''' tag. As, I explored more and complexity increases, I find more and more details of the code which I do not fully understand.

For example, Just have a look at this sandbox-
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-noether-8i6o0

I am still not clear how the key variable passed to animated tag is working under the hood. Moreover, is there is an exhaustive list on which parameters can I pass to animated tag?

Also, is there any good tutorials/resources to understand react-spring in detail? The official document though is quite helpful, doesn't provide enough resolution on micro details of each aspect of it's function.

Answer (score 0):

The `key` prop is not directly related to react-spring, in your example you can see that `string` which is an array uses the `map()` function to map and render animated divs.

`key` is used by React in order to be able to track those elements between changes and be able to determine whether the virtual DOM needs to generate those elements again as a whole or only the new ones that are added. More about keys and lists can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

For more info about react-spring you might find some more information [here](https://aleclarson.github.io/react-spring/v9/#Shorthand-style-props), if you have something specific you would like to achieve feel free to make a question about it, playing with the library and experiencing it yourself will probably be the best way to learn about it.